# How to convert array of array into set in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I have as input:

```
list: [[2, 4], [2, 6], [2, 8]]
```

What I want as output:

```
set: 2,4,6,8
```

What I'm currently doing(not working):

```
def convert(input_list):
    all_nums = set([arr[0], arr[1]] for arr in input_list)
    return all_nums
```

I know I can manually iterate through parent array and add contents of child array to the `set` like this:

```
def convert(input_list):
    all_nums = set()
    for inner_list in input_list:
        all_nums.add(inner_list[0])
        all_nums.add(inner_list[1])
    return all_nums
```

- How to do do that in **pythonic** way?
- In second approach can I do something like `all_nums.add(inner_list[0], inner_list[1])`?

Comment: Do you mean the set should be 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Yup..mistake on my part. Updated the ques

Comment: Where are your 6 and 8 coming from in your expected set? Do you just want a set of all numbers in the flattened input list? In this case `{1, 2, 3, 4}`?

Comment: He updated his input, his output makes sense now.

Comment: @user3483203 In second approach can I do something like all_nums.add(inner_list[0], inner_list[1])?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply:

```
my_list = [[2, 4], [2, 6], [2, 8]]
my_set = {e for l in my_list for e in l}
```

This is using a "set comprehension", which is a squashed down version of:

```
my_list = [[2, 4], [2, 6], [2, 8]]
my_set = set()
for l in my_list:
    for e in l:
        my_set.add(e)
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
my_list = [[2, 4], [2, 6], [2, 8]]
my_set = set()
for l in my_list:
    my_set.update(l)
```

(Variable names shamelessly stolen from [modesitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5030164/modesitt).)

Comment: In second approach can I do something like all_nums.add(inner_list[0], inner_list[1])?

Comment: You need double brackets so you're adding a tuple (immutable, hashable list), but yes. Alternatively, you could do `my_set = {(l[0], l[1]) for l in my_list}` or `my_set = {tuple(l) for l in my_list}` or `my_set = {(x, y) for x, y in my_list}`.

Comment: in second approach doing `all_nums.add((inner_list[0], inner_list[1]))` gives `{(2, 8), (2, 6), (2, 4)}` but **not** {2, 4, 6, 8}

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted...

Comment: is there a way I can get {2, 4, 6, 8} without adding them separately inside for-loop (see the second approach)?

Comment: @noobie Use `my_set.update(inner_list)`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach using `itertools.chain` and `set`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
l = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
print(set(chain.from_iterable(l)))
```

**Output:**

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

- `chain` to flatten the list

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import chain

l = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
l = list(chain.from_iterable(l))
set_l = set(l)
```

Comment: There's no need for the intermediate list, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following

```
set_ = {e for l in my_list for e in l}
```

Comment: Can I steal your variable names? There better than my `x` and `y` (`e`lement and `l`ist, I assume yours are) but my answer has 2 upvotes.

Comment: of course! you won that race condition ;) @wizzwizz4

Answer (score 0):

You can use set comprehension:

```
l = [[2, 4], [2, 6], [2, 8]]
print({i for s in l for i in s})
```

This outputs:

```
{8, 2, 4, 6}
```